# import es6 module returns undefined in one file, but not the other

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-modules

I have the following files in my project:

**Account.js**

```
import User from './User';

const associations = {
    user: {
    type: 'belongsTo',
    model: User
  }
};

class Account {

}

Account.associations = associations;

export default Account;
```

**User.js**

```
import TwitterAccount from './TwitterAccount';

const associations = {
    accounts: {
    type: 'hasMany',
    model: TwitterAccount
  }
};

class User {

}

User.associations = associations;

export default User;
```

The problem I'm encountering is that User.associations returns `{accounts: { type: 'hasMany', model: [Object]}}`, however Account.associations returns: `{users: { type: 'belongsTo', model: undefined }}`.

Now I did try the imports to `const User = require('./User')` and `const Account = require('./Account')`, and this solves the problem but I'm not understanding what is causing this to happen in the first place? I've never had this problem before.

Comment: Google for "circular imports".

Comment: I tried with the same code snippets, it is working fine with "import". Account.associations has User class not undefined. Can you set up a fiddle for your problem ?